# Don't lock questions that migrate and close as "not constructive"?

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, migrated-questions, locked-questions

I've come across a few questions on Programmers that got migrated from SO, closed as "not-constructive", and then locked by the Community user.

I'm assuming the lock is to prevent the question from getting kicked back to SO as a "rejected migration", however it also prevents the questions from ever getting edited and reopened. It also prevents comments to explain the closure to the OP, or to help them improve the question, or asking for any kind of clarification.

Recent examples I've come across: [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/174904/1130) and [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/76738/1130)

Can you make the Community user stop locking migrated questions that get closed?

(I think this only happens with some close reasons, as I noticed closed-as-duplicates do not get locked)

Comment: I don't see *explicit* locks on those questions, but they are locked... doesn't closing post-migration cause automatic "rejected" status, and doesn't the automatic lock accomplish this?

Comment: Both of those questions *did* get rejected (that's why they're locked). The first is unlocked on Stack Overflow, the second got deleted there (and is also unlocked). The point of the lock is to **prevent two alternate versions of the same question** from appearing on both sites, both open and gaining answers. Keep them together.

Comment: Here's a reference for @animuson's comment. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148513/1288 I do wish the lock banner were at least displayed on those posts, since I dislike the invisible lock.  I guess it's rare enough that I encounter these though.

Comment: @Charles _Rejected migration_ means that a question has been migrated, and closed on the site receiving it. It is called _rejected migration_ because closing the question is considered a way not to accept the question.

Answer (score 2):

> however it also prevents the questions from ever getting edited and reopened.

If you feel it ought to be reopened, then  flag it. Your mods  can deal with it then. Or write up a meta post if it's a controversial  issue.

Thing is, this is a *migration*, not *duplication*. It is thus necessary to have only *one* mutable copy of it. So one of the two copies is locked.

Comment: This is not good: we get SE-bad migrations that are ontopic. We close them pending improvement, but users can't improve their questions. I call bug.