# The delete link isn't there on a question when I expect it

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-delete

On [this closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14032650/do-while-loop-in-turbo-c-becomes-infinite-loop), I see no delete link even though I have 20k rep. Have things changed to hide the delete link if I'm out of delete votes (which I'm not sure that I am)? Or is the migrated status of this question gumming something up?

Comment: `edit` is greyed out too, probably related..

Comment: Related: [What is the reason for locking a question migrated from another site that is then closed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147766)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That question was migrated from Programmers. Closing it as "too localized" **rejected the migration**, which sent it back to Programmers and locked the question here. It will get automatically deleted in a month.

Comment: This ends up looking weird because we can only show two banners below the question, so the fact that it's locked doesn't turn up unless you look in the revision history.

Comment: @AnnaLear: Or hover over the disabled edit link. ;P I propose that the *existing* "migrated from" banner just be tweaked to say "migration rejected from". Clear, yes? Of course, then you'd have to know that a rejection means the post is locked.

Comment: Make it "migration from xyz rejected" and we have a deal.

Comment: Ah, see, the links aren't disabled for me. :P I don't have a preference for changing the banner or not. (Though if we're going to do it, Daniel Fischer's version sounds nicer.)