# Why was this question automatically deleted by the Community♦ user?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

[This question on Drupal Answers Meta](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1086/do-we-need-more-moderators) was deleted by the Community user 10 days after I closed it as too localized. Why?

[image: screenshot]

The question was:

- Asked on this very site on October 2012, and migrated the same day on *Drupal Answers Meta*
- Closed as too localized on January 2013
- Deleted on January 2013, 10 days after it was closed

The question's score is 13, and it has an answer with a score of 18.

Another strange fact is that the answer has a pending undelete vote.

[image: screenshot]

Why was the question automatically deleted?

Comment: I also heard that Community♦ threatened to rage quit last week, might be time for an intervention.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Dammit... stop commenting while I'm taking a sip of my drink!

Comment: @WesleyMurch Time for firing it! (Or should I say _fire him_, or _fire her_?)

Comment: Ever since Community♦ started wearing all those fancy hats of Christmas s/he's become a law unto themselves!

Comment: @Jim I was expecting an edit from the Community user. Now, that would have been funny. `;)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rejected migration stubs are automatically cleaned up by the system after a certain period of time, as I [previously mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147766/what-is-the-reason-for-locking-a-question-migrated-from-another-site-that-is-the/148513#148513).

Comment: why on earth would that be a rejected migration? If a question about running site X is not on topic on site X's meta, I'm confused...

Comment: The system is indiscriminate here. The post was migrated to the per-site meta, where it was closed as "too localized", which the system took to mean the migration was being rejected.

Comment: Something it seems the moderator didn't know. OK.