# Why was this (native, not migrated) question deleted by Community?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, community-user

[This question on Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26630/by-mishloach-manos) was asked on our site on Feb 27 (last edited then too), remained open, and was deleted by Community on March 30.  It was not [migrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168642/why-was-this-question-automatically-deleted-by-the-community-user) (to or away from us), and there is nothing in the flag history.  (I assume that if, say, it had been deleted as offensive, as a mod I'd see signs of that.)

What happened here?

[image: screen shot]

Comment: That's a related question for sure but doesn't seem to be a duplicate.  Since I got my answer I don't really care, but it seems an odd closure.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Questions that are negatively voted and are not answered are automatically deleted after a month or so.

It's part of an automated self-cleaning process that was probably designed for SO and carried over to all the sites.

Source: [Enable automatic deletion of old, unanswered zero-score questions after a year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year)

Comment: Gimme a sec to find the source. It's been a while...

Comment: If it's not negatively voted, then it's some function of the # of views the question has.

Comment: @MonicaCellio You could create a [tag:feature-request] to have it changed.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: It's a month for negatively-scored questions, and a year for zero-scored questions.

Comment: Excellent -- and once again, MSO comes through for me before I'm allowed to accept the answer. :-)  (I did search, honest!)

Comment: It's quite ironic that an answer to a question about the Community user is [edited](http://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/175250/3) by the Community user.