# Are rejected migrations being handled correctly on MSO?

Tags: support, migration, meta, locked-questions

[This migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193937/why-are-almost-no-questions-every-answered-on-here) from Stack Overflow to Meta Stack Overflow has caught my eye, and I'm wondering if the current system is working as intended.

**Rough Timeline:**

1. [Original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327539/why-are-almost-no-questions-every-answered-on-here) made on Stack Overflow *5hrs ago*
2. [Original post closed](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18327539/revisions) on Stack Overflow and migrated to Meta *4hrs ago*.  Original post automatically locked as a migrated notice.
3. [Migrated post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193937/why-are-almost-no-questions-every-answered-on-here) [closed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/193937/revisions) on Meta as too broad *1hr ago*
4. Post left locked on Meta (without a lock notice) and unlocked but closed on Stack Overflow (migration rejected).

This could well all be by design, it just seems odd to me that the post has been [left locked on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193937/why-are-almost-no-questions-every-answered-on-here) for all eternity.

I have it in my head that migrations from a site to a per-site meta that are then closed on the per site meta too would **not** trigger a rejected migration.  Does this not apply to Meta Stack Overflow?

Comment: There is a lock notice in the [revisions page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/193937/revisions), you just have to reach it manually since the question was never edited. And I think such questions get auto deleted after a while. (week or month)

Comment: Migrations to MSO should definitely *not* trigger a rejected migration. MSO is a black hole, questions cannot be migrated out of it, so it should not be able to reject migrations either.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I did wonder about auto deletion - would it apply in this case due to the +5 answers on the post?

Comment: @Rory answers are not relevant, it's not the "cleaner process" that clean old and unanswered questions but rather a different one. I'm looking for some source, still not 100% sure such thing exists.

Comment: OK, you might have a point here. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126982/152859). I asked Kevin now, let's hope he reply soon.

Comment: It should eventually be deleted, yeah (Relevant: [What is the reason for locking a question migrated from another site that is then closed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147766)). But I'm not sure as to the whole main -> meta question.