# Square brackets for migrated questions

Tags: support, search, migration

I did a [search for migrated questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=migrated%3Ayes). In result list some post titles contains a `[migrated]` text, but most of them - don't.

> [image: example]

As fas as I see `[migrated]` only appended to closed post (e.g. as duplicate), but not for protected or locked. Opened questions also not contain such text in title.

Why `[migrated]` appers only for closed questions?

Comment: I think those questions were migrated before the advent of adding `[migrated]` to the question title.

Comment: @ale I don't think so... try to sort results by newest. Many of recent questions don't have such adding.

Comment: False positive, then. The ones with "[migrated]" in the displayed title have been migrated _away_. The search apparently also includes questions migrated _to_ the current site. Try searching `migrated:1 closed:1`.

Comment: @ale seems `[migrated]` appears if post is migrated *away* or (migrated *to* & closed). If post migrated *to* and not closed yet - it's not marked with `[migrated]`.

Comment: That's what I just said.

Comment: I think to convey the idea that it is locked because it is `[migrated]` and closed, so, you can't edit or answer it.

Comment: @Pandya how do you explain [locked+migrated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=migrated%3Ayes+locked%3Ayes)?

Comment: @alexolut I think you'll see `[migrated]` on question which are migrated **to** (not *from*) any other site *from* MSE (or the site on which you're searching). (and for closed as [said](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290238/square-brackets-for-migrated-questions?noredirect=1#comment942382_290238))

Comment: For migrated+closed=locked, visit [What is the reason for locking a question migrated from another site that is then closed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147766/260388)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For migrated questions, append {migrated} to the title, instead of {closed}](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10641/for-migrated-questions-append-migrated-to-the-title-instead-of-closed) (i.e. it's only for closed questions because it's a *replacement* for [closed])